# Equivalent of the AWS S3 SDK TransferUtility.deleteTransferRecord() function on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my Android app, I download files from an AWS S3 bucket.

When the download is complete, or when I need to cancel it, I use the following function to keep everything clean:

```kotlin
TransferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(id: Int)
```

Now, I want to do the same on iOS, but I don't manage to do it, and can't find any documentation on that.

What's the equivalent of the `TransferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(id: Int)` function on iOS (using Swift)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS technical support, there is no equivalent on iOS, and there is no need to worry about that.